Redirected Defects
I have a defect "application a" which was created yesterday and during the analysis, it was found the defect has to be redirected to application b, and hence the defect has changed its name from application a to application b, and this is been recorded under activity tab also. now using filter if i have to retrieve the defects which was redirected using JQL, and output should be key application a, key application b, created date  etc.. how to perform this using JQL. Many thanks in advance.
I was not able to find anything till date to fetch something from activity tab or work history tab to retrieve and display. hence approached here.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
